# How to render products array of each order in an orders array

Tags: reactjs

[this is the screen shot of array of orders ,this array has 5 orders and each order has an products array as shown how to render products array of each order ]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/66E1L.png

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you loop through and render your orders and in every order, you loop through and render all the order's products and their data

```
{orders.map(order =>
    <div className="order">
        // some order data here

        {order.products.map(product =>
            <div className="product">
                {product.name}

                // product data here
            </div>
        )}
    </div>
)}
```